# Octave compare two arrays

Tags: arrays, octave

Given two column  vectors,I need to compare each element of the vector a with the  first element of vector b in the first iteration and return a logical array. Then the second element of vector b with each element of vector a and return a logical array so forth. The number of logical arrays is equal to the number of elements in vector b.

```
a=1:10;
b=[5 6 7];
for j=1:length(b),
 for i=1:10,
    c=b(j)==a(i);
  end;
end;
```

ex:
after the first  iteration of inner loop need to return [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
a = 1:10
b = [5 6 7]
output = zeros(3,10);
for i = 1:length(b)
    output(i,:) = (a == b(:,i)) %  b(:, i) meas using index get the value
end


output =

   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: If this is the desired output he can just do `output = a == b'` without any loop

Comment: yes , it is a better way to do this, I learn something new from you.  :-)